# Is the number of elements$g$ in a finite Abelian group $G$ such that the $| g|= k$ always equal to a multiple of $\varphi(k)$?

Tags: group-theory, number-theory

Let $G $ be a finite Abelian group.  I know that if $G$ is cyclic then there are exactly $\varphi(k)$ elements in $G$ that have order $k$ for each $k$ that divides $|G|$. I also know that $G$ can be written as a group direct product of cyclic groups.  This gives me a hazy notion that the number of elements $g$ in $G$ that have order $k$ is a multiple of $\varphi(k)$.  In other words, it seems like if I construct a cycle graph of $G$ then every element must be on some cycle C and that on this cycle there would be exactly $\varphi(k)$ elements of order $k$ for each $k$ that divides the length of the cycle $C$.

What I am ultimately trying to prove is that the number of elements in a modulo multiplication group that have order $2$ is always odd.  (for $n>2$).

Comment: For your "ultimate" question, if a group has even order (as is the case for all $\mathbb Z_n^\times, n>2$), then the map $x\mapsto x^{-1}$ is an involution and must fix an even number of elements. But it fixes the identity and all elements of order $2$, so the number of elements of order $2$ must be odd.

Also, your conjecture would state that the number of elements of order $2$ is a multiple of $1$, which is trivially true.

Comment: So would you agree that for k>2, the number of elements in a modulo multiplication group Z*_n, n>2  that have order k is always even.

Comment: Since phi(k) is even for k>2.

Comment: Yeah, that's right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your conjecture is true. For every $x\in G$, let $C_x$ consist of all powers of $x$ whose order is equal to that of $x$. It's not too hard to check that the $C_x$'s partition $G$ into equivalence classes. The size of $C_x$ is equal to $\phi(|x|)$. Thus, every element of order $k$ is in a class with $\phi(k)$ elements, and thus the number of elements of order $k$ is a multiple of $\phi(k)$.

Comment: Yes, I think your proof is clearing up my hazy notion.  Just for fun I classified the elements in Z*_21 according to your equivalence relation.  C_1={1}, C_2={2,11}, C_4={4,16}, C_5={5,17}, C_8={8} C_10={10,19}, C_13={13}, C_20={20}.  Everything seems to be in order.  In particular note:  |2| = 6  and |C_2| = phi(6) = 2.